# PJSIP build for iphone error

Tags: ios, xcode, pjsip

I'm following the tutorial here:

`http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone`

But I'm always getting compiler errors on building the project.

Basically after doing:

Just run:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ ./configure-iphone
$ make dep && make clean && make
```

These commands seem to run fine. I run them on the home folder of the project.
Then I open `ipjsua.xcodeproj` using Xcode in `pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/ipjsua` and build the project.

And I get:

```
ld: library not found for -lgsmcodec-arm-apple-darwin9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Before I was getting different library linker errors too.

Can anyone post a good tutorial on this?